# 'Input string was not in a correct format' em texbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Pessoal estou tentando fazer com que um textbox meu exiba o valor de uma mensalidade, porém quando eu digito o numero ele vai normal, quando apago os numeros e chega em um ponto ou virgula ele da esse erro de 'Input string was not in a correct format'.

eu estou utilizando o código abaixo para converter para moeda:

```
    private void tb_mensalidade_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            decimal nMoeda = Convert.ToDecimal(Mensalidade.Text);
            string mascara = String.Format("{0:N2}", nMoeda);
            this.Mensalidade.Text = mascara;
    }
```

se alguém puder me dar uma força de como posso resolver isso vou agradecer imensamente!!

Comment: A moeda brasileira não tem ponto e vírgula desde o Império (na maior parte do mundo também não tem), portanto o erro faz todo sentido quando você tira o números e chega em um ponto-e-vírgula.

Comment: @CésarRodriguez não é um ponto-e-vírgula e sim somente ponto ou somente vírgula, por exemplo 29,00 ou 2.900,00.

Comment: o formato esperado é "2900" ou "2900.00", ou seja, sem separador de milhares, e o ponto como separador de decimais. Aqui tem no site tem muitas perguntas sobre como mudar o formato sugiro pesquisar... pesquise também por `Replace` para substituir vírgula por ponto

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Digamos que você insira o valor 2900. O Mensalidade terá o valor formatado para "2.900,00".

O erro talvez possa estar no momento em que você apaga o texto do Mensalidade e chega por exemplo no valor ".900,00" a conversão para decimal dá erro pois não consegue converter tal string.

Talvez para resolver isso você possa estar adicionando algumas verificações antes de converter o valor.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPreco.Text))
{
    return;
}
else if (!char.IsDigit(txtPreco.Text[0]))
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: vou testar e jaja volto com o resultado, mas ja adianto por enquanto muito obrigado!!

Comment: cara funcionou, simples mas não tinha pensado nisso, obrigado mesmo, você não tem ideia do quanto me ajudou!!!